# Spring CGLIB, transactions and private final field initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, cglib

I have the following class hierarchy in my Spring Boot application:

```
public abstract class A {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public void method1(Object object) {
        this.objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    }

}

@Component
public class B extends A {

    public void method2() {
        method1();
    }

}
```

in such case everything is working fine.

But when I add `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)` annotation to `method2()` declaration, like for example:

```
public abstract class A {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public void method1() {
        this.objectMapper; // always NULL
    }

}

@Component
public class B extends A {

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void method2() {
        method1();
    }

}
```

and execute `method2()` it fails with `NullPointerException` in `method1()` because of `this.objectMapper` is `NULL`;

How to let Spring correctly initialize the `private final ObjectMapper objectMapper` even in case of `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)` is added?

Also, in case of `@Transactional` annotation the class of `this` is `B$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB` and without annotation is just plain `B`. So, looks like CGLIB unable to properly initialize `private final ObjectMapper objectMapper`.. Is there any workarounds how it can be solved?

Comment: See https://deinum.biz/2020-07-03-Autowired-Field-Null/#aop for a broader explanation. Mainly due to proxies, remove the `final` keyword from `method2` else it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `final` in your code. You are using `@Transactional` with `CGLIB`. How `CGLIB` works is it creates a proxy by extending your class. Since the below method is final it cannot extend it, since final classes cannot be extended.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)

public final void method2() {
    method1();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is it possible to do with reflection api or something like this? Because mentioned code in my example is a part of 3rdparty lib.

Comment: I think you can use ReflectionUtils.setField("objectmapper",this.getClass().getSuperclass(), new ObjectMapper());